# merging multiple <canvas> issue

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, globalcompositeoperation

I'm designing a simple app for which I need to use multiple **globalCompositeOperation**, and therefore I need to use multiple hidden  items, then merge them to get the final result.

one of the canvas items is used to **drawImage()** and then use it as an alpha mask.

I assumed that on 2nd canvas if I use to draw 1st canvas, it will copy it exactly so I can add 2nd thing on top of it. It does copy only the **fillRect()** and ignores the **drawImage()** function...

Any idea how can I forward entire content of the first canvas to 2nd? I need the masked part to move to the 2nd canvas.

Been stuck on it for hours and need your help. Tried to use **toDataUrl("image/png")** and then output that into 2nd canvas, but getting same results :(

simplified version under:
http://jsfiddle.net/EbVmm/17/

Thanks

```
var c1 = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var c2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");

function drawScene(mainColour) {

    var ctx = c1.getContext("2d");

    var alphaPath = "http://eskarian.com/images/alpha-test.png";
    var alphaObj = new Image();
    alphaObj.src = alphaPath;

    ctx.fillStyle = mainColour;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 300);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'xor';
    alphaObj.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(alphaObj, 0, 0);
    };
};

function addScene(colour) {
    var ctx2 = c2.getContext("2d");

    ctx2.drawImage(c1, 0, 0);
    ctx2.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    ctx2.fillStyle = colour;
    ctx2.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100);

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use alphaObj before it is fully loaded.

Try something like this:

```
var c1 = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var c2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");

var alphaPath = "http://eskarian.com/images/alpha-test.png";
var alphaObj = new Image();
alphaObj.onload = function () {
    drawScene(mainColour);
    addScene(colour)
};
alphaObj.src = alphaPath;


function drawScene(mainColour) {
    var ctx = c1.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(alphaObj, 0, 0);
    ctx.fillStyle = mainColour;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 300);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'xor';
};

function addScene(colour) {
    var ctx2 = c2.getContext("2d");
    ctx2.drawImage(c1, 0, 0);
    ctx2.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    ctx2.fillStyle = colour;
    ctx2.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100);
};
```

Comment: Thanks, such easy thing to do -.- been over thinking too much while the solution was so simple :) Btw there is just one slight change I had to do in your code. 

`ctx.drawImage(alphaObj, 0, 0);` needs to be after 
    `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'xor';` for the alpha to work properly. Other than that, it works like a charm :)